# Having problem with sticking one facet of the cube to the other side

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to create a popup box with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.
Everything went right until I wanted the hinged fifth face of the cube to move on its first.
The problem is that the fifth dimension is separated from the first one when the animation is executed.
Clicking on the cube opens it and closes it again

[A Fidel of this cube is inserted here](https://jsfiddle.net/sepehr2007/63n2sk9u/13/)

```js
let cube = document.querySelector('.cube'),
    optionsArea = document.querySelector('.options'),
    area = document.querySelectorAll('.area'),
    zoom = optionsArea.querySelector('#zoom'),
    rotateX = optionsArea.querySelector('#rotate-x'),
    rotateY = optionsArea.querySelector('#rotate-y'),
    rotateZ = optionsArea.querySelector('#rotate-z'),
    lastZoom = -150,
    lastRotateZ = 0,
    lastRotateY = 0,
    lastRotateX = 0;
    /*areaRotateArray = [0,180,90,-90,90,-90];*/

    let initialAnimation = [
        [
            {index:2 , rx:0 , ry:0 , rz:0 , t:'0,0,200px' , timeOut:0 , origin:'bottom'},
            {index:3 , rx:-90 , ry:-90 , rz:0 , t:'0,0,0' , timeOut:0 , origin:'bottom right'},
            {index:4 , rx:90 , ry:90 , rz:180 , t:'0,0,0' , timeOut:0 , origin:'bottom left'}
        ],
        [
            {index:5 , rx:0 , ry:0 , rz:0 , t:'0,-200px,0' , timeOut:500 , origin:'bottom center'},
            {index:1 , rx:0 , ry:0 , rz:0 , t:'0,0,0' , timeOut:500 , origin:'bottom'}
        ],
        [
            {index:5 , rx:-90 , ry:0 , rz:0 , t:'0,-200px,0' , timeOut:1000 , origin:'bottom center'}
        ]
    ];

    let areasAnimationArray = [
        [
            {index:5 , rx:0 , ry:0 , rz:0 , t:'0,-200px,0' , timeOut:0 , origin:'bottom center'}
        ],
        [
            {index:5 , rx:90 , ry:0 , rz:0 , t:'0,-200px,0' , timeOut:500 , origin:'400px 400px'},
            {index:1 , rx:90 , ry:0 , rz:0 , t:'0,0,0' , timeOut:500 , origin:'bottom'}
        ],
        [
            {index:2 , rx:-90 , ry:0 , rz:0 , t:'0,0,200px' , timeOut:1000 , origin:'bottom'},
            {index:3 , rx:-90 , ry:-180 , rz:0 , t:'0,0,0' , timeOut:1000 , origin:'bottom right'},
            {index:4 , rx:90 , ry:0 , rz:180 , t:'0,0,0' , timeOut:1000 , origin:'bottom left'}
        ]
    ];

    zoom.addEventListener('input' , function () {
        lastZoom = this.value;
        setStyle();
    });
    rotateZ.addEventListener('input' , function () {
        lastRotateZ = this.value;
        setStyle();
    });
    rotateY.addEventListener('input' , function () {
        lastRotateY = this.value;
        setStyle();
    });
    rotateX.addEventListener('input' , function () {
        lastRotateX = this.value;
        setStyle();
    });

    cube.addEventListener('click' , function () {
        if (! cube.classList.contains('opened')) {
            cube.classList.add('opened');
            doAnimation(areasAnimationArray);
        } else {
            cube.classList.remove('opened');
            doAnimation(initialAnimation);
        }
    });

    function setStyle() {
        cube.style = `transform: translateZ( ${lastZoom}px ) rotateZ(${lastRotateZ}deg) rotateY(${lastRotateY}deg) rotateX(${lastRotateX}deg);`;
    }

    function toggleStyle(object) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            let index = object.index - 1;
            area[index].style = `transform-origin:${object.origin}; transform: translate3d(${object.t}) rotateX(${object.rx}deg) rotateY(${object.ry}deg) rotateZ(${object.rz}deg);`;
        } , object.timeOut);
    }

    function doAnimation(animationArray) {
        animationArray.forEach(function (value,index) {
            if (value instanceof Array){
                value.map(toggleStyle);
            }
        });
    }
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}

.cube-wrapper {
  height: 450px;
}

.cube-playground {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
  line-height: 200px;
}

.cube {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform:rotateY(100deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  /*background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.21);
            border-bottom: 1px solid red;
            border-top: 1px solid blue;
            border-right: 1px solid yellow;
            border-left: 1px solid green;*/
}

.area {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /*border: 2px solid black;*/
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

.area:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.6);
}

.area:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.6);
}

.area:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.6);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}

.area:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: rgba(210, 105, 30, 0.6);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}

.area:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transform-origin: bottom center;
  /*height: 200%;*/
}

.area:nth-child(6) {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.61);
}

.options .item label {
  display: block;
  color: wheat;
}

.origin-100 {
  transform-origin: 100% 270%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    
</head>
<body>

<div class="cube-wrapper">
    <div class="cube-playground">
        <div class="cube">
            <div style="transform: translate3d(0,0,0)" class="area">1</div>
            <div style="transform: translate3d(0,0,200px)" class="area">2</div>
            <div style="transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg)" class="area">3</div>
            <div style="transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotateX(90deg) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(180deg)" class="area">4</div>
            <div style="transform: translate3d(0,-200px,0) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0)" class="area">5</div>
            <div style="transform: translate3d(0,0,0) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0)" class="area">6</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="options">
    <div class="item">
        <label for="zoom">zoom</label>
        <input id="zoom" type="range" min="-250" max="150" step="1" value="-150" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <label for="rotate-x">rotate x</label>
        <input id="rotate-x" type="range" min="0" max="360" step="-360" value="0" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <label for="rotate-y">rotate y</label>
        <input id="rotate-y" type="range" min="0" max="360" step="-360" value="0" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <label for="rotate-z">rotate z</label>
        <input id="rotate-z" type="range" min="0" max="360" step="-360" value="0" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple trick to solving this problem.
Putting the second side of the cube inside the first side of the cube will cause the two sides to not separate when moving. Of course, the animations queue should be rewritten accordingly.

```js
 let cube = document.querySelector('.cube'),
    optionsArea = document.querySelector('.options'),
    area = document.querySelectorAll('.area'),
    zoom = optionsArea.querySelector('#zoom'),
    rotateX = optionsArea.querySelector('#rotate-x'),
    rotateY = optionsArea.querySelector('#rotate-y'),
    rotateZ = optionsArea.querySelector('#rotate-z'),
    lastZoom = -150,
    lastRotateZ = 0,
    lastRotateY = 0,
    lastRotateX = 0;

    let initialAnimation = [
        [
            {index:3 , rx:0 , ry:0 , rz:0 , t:'0,0,200px' , timeOut:0},
            {index:4 , rx:-90 , ry:-90 , rz:0 , t:'0,0,0' , timeOut:0},
            {index:5 , rx:90 , ry:90 , rz:180 , t:'0,0,0' , timeOut:0}
        ],
        [

            {index:1 , rx:0 , ry:0 , rz:0 , t:'0,0,0' , timeOut:500}
        ],
        [
            {index:2 , rx:-90 , ry:0 , rz:0 , t:'0,0,0' , timeOut:1000}
        ]
    ];

    let areasAnimationArray = [
        [
            {index:2 , rx:30 , ry:0 , rz:0 , t:'0,0,0' , timeOut:0},
            {index:1 , rx:5 , ry:0 , rz:0 , t:'0,0,0' , timeOut:0}
        ],
        [
            {index:2 , rx:15 , ry:0 , rz:0 , t:'0,0,0' , timeOut:1000},
            {index:1 , rx:2 , ry:0 , rz:0 , t:'0,0,0' , timeOut:1000}
        ],
        [
            {index:2 , rx:45 , ry:0 , rz:0 , t:'0,0,0' , timeOut:2000},
            {index:1 , rx:10 , ry:0 , rz:0 , t:'0,0,0' , timeOut:2000}
        ],
        [
            {index:2 , rx:10 , ry:0 , rz:0 , t:'0,0,0' , timeOut:3000},
            {index:1 , rx:5 , ry:0 , rz:0 , t:'0,0,0' , timeOut:3000}
        ],
        [
            {index:2 , rx:0 , ry:0 , rz:0 , t:'0,0,0' , timeOut:4000},
            {index:1 , rx:90 , ry:0 , rz:0 , t:'0,0,0' , timeOut:4000}
        ],
        [
            {index:3 , rx:-90 , ry:0 , rz:0 , t:'0,0,200px' , timeOut:5000},
            {index:4 , rx:-90 , ry:-180 , rz:0 , t:'0,0,0' , timeOut:5000},
            {index:5 , rx:90 , ry:0 , rz:180 , t:'0,0,0' , timeOut:5000}
        ]
    ];

    zoom.addEventListener('input' , function () {
        lastZoom = this.value;
        setStyle();
    });
    rotateZ.addEventListener('input' , function () {
        lastRotateZ = this.value;
        setStyle();
    });
    rotateY.addEventListener('input' , function () {
        lastRotateY = this.value;
        setStyle();
    });
    rotateX.addEventListener('input' , function () {
        lastRotateX = this.value;
        setStyle();
    });

    cube.addEventListener('click' , function () {
        if (cube.classList.contains('enable')){
            cube.classList.remove('enable');
            if (! cube.classList.contains('opened')) {
                cube.classList.add('opened');
                doAnimation(areasAnimationArray , function () {
                    cube.classList.add('enable')
                });

            } else {
                cube.classList.remove('opened');
                doAnimation(initialAnimation , function () {
                    cube.classList.add('enable')
                });
            }
        }
    });

    function setStyle() {
        cube.style = `transform: translateZ( ${lastZoom}px ) rotateZ(${lastRotateZ}deg) rotateY(${lastRotateY}deg) rotateX(${lastRotateX}deg);`;
    }

    function toggleStyle(object) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            let index = object.index - 1;
            area[index].style = `transform: translate3d(${object.t}) rotateX(${object.rx}deg) rotateY(${object.ry}deg) rotateZ(${object.rz}deg);`;
        } , object.timeOut);
    }

    function doAnimation(animationArray , callback) {
        animationArray.forEach(function (value,index) {
            if (value instanceof Array){
                value.map(toggleStyle);
            }
        });
        callback();
    }
```

```css
body{
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: black;
        }
        .cube-wrapper{
            height: 450px;
        }
        .cube-playground{
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            perspective: 1000px;
            perspective-origin: 50% 100px;
            position: relative;
            margin: auto;
            margin-top: 150px;
            line-height: 200px;
        }
        .cube{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            transform: rotateY(100deg);
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            /*background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.21);
            border-bottom: 1px solid red;
            border-top: 1px solid blue;
            border-right: 1px solid yellow;
            border-left: 1px solid green;*/
        }
        .area{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            /*border: 2px solid black;*/
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 5rem;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: .5s ease-in-out;
            transform-origin: bottom;
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
        }
        .cube > .area:nth-child(1){
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.6);
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

        }
        .cube > .area:nth-child(2){
            background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.6);
        }
        .cube > .area:nth-child(3){
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.6);
            transform-origin: bottom right;
        }
        .cube > .area:nth-child(4){
            background-color: rgba(210, 105, 30, 0.6);
            transform-origin: bottom left;
        }
        .cube > .area:nth-child(5){
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.61);
        }
        .cube .area.child{
            background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
            top: -100%;
        }
        .options .item label{
            display: block;
            color: wheat;
        }
        .origin-100{
            transform-origin: 100% 270%;
        }
        /*.open-area{
            transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(150px);
            transform-origin: bottom;
        }*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
   
</head>
<body>

<div class="cube-wrapper">
    <div class="cube-playground">
        <div class="cube enable">
            <div style="transform: translate3d(0,0,0)" class="area">1
                <div style="transform: rotateX(-90deg)" class="area child">2</div>
            </div>
            <div style="transform: translate3d(0,0,200px)" class="area">3</div>
            <div style="transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg)" class="area">4</div>
            <div style="transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotateX(90deg) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(180deg)" class="area">5</div>
            <div style="transform: translate3d(0,0,0) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0)" class="area">6</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="options">
    <div class="item">
        <label for="zoom">zoom</label>
        <input id="zoom" type="range" min="-250" max="150" step="1" value="-150" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <label for="rotate-x">rotate x</label>
        <input id="rotate-x" type="range" min="0" max="360" step="-360" value="0" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <label for="rotate-y">rotate y</label>
        <input id="rotate-y" type="range" min="0" max="360" step="-360" value="0" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <label for="rotate-z">rotate z</label>
        <input id="rotate-z" type="range" min="0" max="360" step="-360" value="0" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
</div>
```